# Applying predefined function to batch in tensorflow

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, tensorflow

I have a function, written in tensorflow, which manipulates arrays. It takes in 2d arrays and performs some operations on a part of the array, then outputs an array of the same size and shape, but with modified elements. My problem is that, in my model, I don't get just one array at a time, I get a batch of shape (batch_size, array_size, channel). Since the channel is usually mono, the input batch is a 4D tensor. 
Is there any way in which I can apply my function to every layer (matrix) in this 4D tensor, without significantly modifying the function?

The function is something like:

```
def myFunction(matrix):
     # function body
     return another_matrix
```

How could I apply this to a batch of 5 such matrices?

Answer (score 0):

[tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/functional_ops/higher_order_operators#map_fn)

It applies `f` to each element, in your case to each 2D array. These 2D arrays are obtained by unpacking the second parameter.

Comment: Since the first dimension is my batch size, shouldn't I unstack (unpack seems to be deprecated) along the first dimension? I was thinking something like matrix = tf.unstack(batch) then output = tf.map_fn(myFunction, matrix), but it does not seem to understand that.

Comment: Your 0th dimension is batch size. 'map_fn' automatically unpacks along that dimension.